# Any way to link to specific content type without custom field? Exposed contextual filter?

Tags: 8

I want a field that links to a content type, but only one type, and I want the user to choose which type.  I thought an EntityReference view would solve my problem, because that can even take arguments to pass to its contextual filters, but you have to set the argument ahead of time, and I want it to be exposed to the user.

Currently I'm using a reference field to Content, but I want to at least limit the results of the ajax autocomplete to only the content type they've chosen to reference.

Comment: `link to a specific content type` - what does this mean?

Comment: I'm using a Content Reference field from core.  It allows you to select which content types are allowed to be referenced.  But, it doesn't allow the user to select this dynamically, it has to be predefined.